# Is there a simple way to check whether a SQL statement will update the database?

Tags: c#, sql

I have a chunk of code that does something like this:

```
if (sqlStatement.WillUpdateDatabase)
  DoThing1();
else 
  DoThing2();
```

Currently `WillUpdateDatabase`is implemented as

```
public bool WillUpdateDatabase {
  get { return statementText.StartsWith("SELECT"); }
}
```

This catches the majority of cases, but it gets more complicated with `SELECT ... INTO ...`. And there are possibly a few other cases that I might need to take into account.

**Just to be clear:** this is not to implement any type of security. There are other systems that check for SQL injection attacks, this bit of code just needs to make a choice whether to do thing1 or thing2.

This seems like it should be a solved problem. Is there an industry standard way to do this reliably?

**Update/clarification:** Something like `UPDATE Table1 SET Column1 = 'a' WHERE 1 = 2` should be treated as an update.

Comment: Can't you do `.Contains("UPDATE")` and `.Contains("INSERT")`?

Comment: @Jonny What if the SQL contains an `UPDATE` but a `WHERE` clause such that no records will be updated. Does that count as 'will update the database'?

Comment: You can't predict if it will update a value until it effectively tries it... So no you can't really check this

Comment: I'd turn this around and demand that callers call method #1 or method #2 depending on whether *they* were going to do updates or not. The combination of allowing arbitrary SQL but also having to figure out what that SQL does is a nasty one. Yes, in theory, you can parse the SQL and verify if there are any non-`SELECT` statements in there (`TSqlParser` is a thing), since that could be conservatively considered "updating" (including stuff like `CREATE INDEX`). In practice, I'd be wary of the reliability of such an approach. At the very least you're tied to SQL Server that way.

Comment: It would help if we knew the nature of `DoThing1` and `DoThing2` - there may be ways to combine them that you're not aware of such that the distinction doesn't need to be made. Other than that, I can think of one way but it involves sending the query to the server anyway - would that be acceptable here? Again, not knowing the bigger picture makes anything highly speculative.

Comment: And I think I'd agree with Jeroen - the "industry standard way" is "don't run arbitrary SQL".

Comment: Here's another one: how about figuring out if `EXEC MyProcedureThatSelectsOnlyData` performs an update? A conservative check would have to say yes, since a stored procedure could do anything, but now you're prevented from using stored procedures to do complicated things. What about using temporary tables, are those "updates" or do they not count since you're not really modifying the main database? This is just all round a nasty problem. The short answer to your question would be "no" -- there's no *simple* way to do this, at least not one that's reliable in general.

Comment: @mjwills - I've update my question, but yes UPDATE counts as an update even if there are no changes applied.

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert - that was the answer I was looking for, even if it wasn't the answer I was hoping for

Answer (score 3):

As many others have commented, this really is a nasty problem and inspecting the SQL isn't really ever going to cut it for you because you'll practically end up writing an entire SQL parser (and that really would be reinventing the wheel). You'll probably have to make a database user that only has read permissions for all tables, then actually execute the query you want to test using that read-only user and catch the situations where it fails because of permission violations, (rather than SQL syntax etc)

Answer (score -2):

Since your statement text will change values only with the SQL queries beginning with `UPDATE` or `INSERT`, one way to test if you query will try to update could be the following :

```
public bool WillUpdateDatabase {
    get { return (statementText.StartsWith("UPDATE") || statementText.StartsWith("INSERT") ) }
}
```

But you cannot know if the query will effectively update some fields in the table. As an example, if your query is like `UPDATE persons SET age = 25 WHERE name = "John"` and there is no entry with name *John*, your query will try to update, but will obviously not be able to because there is nothing to update.

**EDIT**

Thanks to @NikBo and @Gusman, I replaced *Contains* with *StartsWith* to avoid any issue like Nik Bo explained in the comments bellow.

Comment: This would return true with this statement `SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Field1 = 'UPDATE"`

Comment: Use StartsWith instead of Contains.

Comment: `;With SomeCTE() update table1...` doesn't cause updates then?

Comment: I don't think this is a good answer to the question, sorry. It's simply not comprehensive enough, and this approach likely never will be

Comment: I tried to be a little bit more comprehensive.I agree that the approach is not a good one, but I just tried to answer the question